# How to search a bunch of keywords in an ASP.Net solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have about **600** keywords, that all of them are needed to be searched in a very massive **.Net** solution to find out which one of them has never been used. Is there any fast way to do this task, instead of having to find them one by one by using **ctrl + F** (in Visual studio)? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are these keywords stored? This would be important to know before anyone could suggest a methodology for you to use

Comment: These are **stored procedure names**, which may have been executed in the projects.

Comment: I hope to never work on a project that has 600 stored procedures in it. May I ask how your project came to be like that?

Comment: This is not **MY** project! I am a new team member of this project. All of that has been developed years before.

Comment: I think it's best to be able to use regular [`ctrl + F`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2022), I can't think of any other way.

Comment: You can do the job in a few minutes with a simple C# console application. How hard is it to get all files from a root folder, read them all and search for keywords in a list...?

Comment: I will be very grateful if you answer that question, instead of asking me about the difficulty and giving negative score! @JérômeMEVEL

Comment: This question clearly lacks of research beforehand hence my downvote. On StackOverflow  you should show us what you've tried already when posting a question. I advise you to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: this is a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Found the solution. I post it, maybe it is useful for someone.
I created a simple `Node.js` project and installed a package ([find-in-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-in-files)) for searching text patterns across multiple files in any sub-directory. So this is the code:

```
const seeker = require("find-in-files");
const fs = require('fs');

//read the file containing 600 stored procedure names
fs.readFile('600SPs.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    //split the string based on new lines and put each keyword in the array.
    const lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);  

    //make sure there is no white spaces
    const trimmedLines = lines.map(line=>line.trim());

    //show a message to user to wait till async task is finished.
    console.log("please wait...");

    //create a regex to match any of the keywords while searching files.

    const boundryTrimmedLines = trimmedLines.map(value=>(`\\b${value}\\b`));
    const regExText = boundryTrimmedLines.join("|");
    
    //call find function of find-in-files package which can search through all of the files 
    // in the given directory and its sub directories that have .cs format
    seeker.find(regExText, "D:\\TestProj\\ParentDir",".cs$")
    .then(res=>{
        //res is based on files pathes having the keywords
        //what is intended is keywords based on the file pathes
        //so res format should be modified.
        var rawAnswers = [];
        Object.keys(res).map(key=>{
            const rawElement = {
                address:key,
                matchedCases:res[key].matches
            };
            rawAnswers.push(rawElement);
        })
        var finalAnswer = [];
        trimmedLines.map(word=>{
            let finalItem = {
                word,
                addresses:[]
            }
            rawAnswers.map(rawAnswer=>{
                if(rawAnswer.matchedCases.some(i=>i==word)){
                    finalItem.addresses.push(rawAnswer.address);
                }
            })
            finalAnswer.push(finalItem);
        })
        
        //write finalAnswer to a json file
        fs.writeFile("answer.json",JSON.stringify(finalAnswer,null,2),function(error){
            if(error)
                console.log("not created.");
            else    
                console.log("created successfully.")
        })
    })
});
```

For more information, this is part of `600SPs.txt` file (each `SP` name, placed in a line) :

```
New9090_Ras
New9090_Ras2
NewDrawingData
NewDrawingDataSelect
ProcedureName
R_CLVQ
RFM_py_AEKAL
SaveDynamicMenu
setFinalUpdateMenueId
```

And this is part of the final result (`answer.json`) :

[image]